# ImportError: No module named layers.recurrent

Tags: python

Here I'm getting a import error but it didn't specify in which file i'm getting this error. Please take a look at exception trace

```
(py36) pratyusha@pratyusha-Q304UAK:~/Projects/ronin$ python Retrieval-Eval.py
No handlers could be found for logger "gensim.models.doc2vec"
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
2018-03-14 02:53:15,922 - neon.neon - DISPLAY - dataset files /home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/examples/skipthought/output/doc__books_txt_1_.h5 and vocabulary file /home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/examples/skipthought/output/doc__books_txt_1_.vocab already exist. will use cached data. 
2018-03-14 02:53:15,923 - neon.neon - DISPLAY - 
Vocab size from the dataset is: 257
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 485, in <module>
    e = evaluate(dialogue, dtype="str", concept_weight=1.0, task_weight=0)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 249, in evaluate
    retrieval2 = get_skipsim_matches(selected=questions, dtype="str", conceptW=concept_weight, taskW=task_weight)  #HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 447, in get_skipsim_matches
    conceptDictionary = get_skipsim_concept_dictionary(selected[1:], dtype)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 465, in get_skipsim_concept_dictionary
    scores = get_list_skipsim_scores(selected, dialogue, dtype)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 431, in get_list_skipsim_scores
    score = st.get_sim_score(q1, q2)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 133, in get_sim_score
    a = self.get_sentence_vec(text1)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 80, in get_sentence_vec
    model_dict = load_obj(args.model_file)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/neon/util/persist.py", line 156, in load_obj
    return pickle_load(load_path)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Projects/ronin/neon/neon/util/compat.py", line 54, in pickle_load
    return pickle.load(filepath)
ImportError: No module named layers.recurrent
```

I dont have any import statement regarding layesrs.recurent in persists.py or compat.py

Comment: This can be caused by versions mismatched between two dependent libraries.

Comment: But now I'm using only one version. @AkshayNevrekar